# Java: split array list into chunks where objects have an equal attribute value

Tags: java, list, split, equals

I have an ArrayList list of objects, say Person

Let's say Person has a boolean attribute of 'eligible'.

I'd like to get a list of index pairs (i,j), such that list.sublist(i,j) has Persons with equal values of eligible. I don't want to modify the list.

Is there an easy way to do this in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using the [`subList()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-); it makes virtual sublists which are actually views into the original list.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your requirements. Could you post some example showing what you want to achieve?

Comment: Your requirement makes no sense; it looks like you want to sort the list in some way or another and yet want to have certain persons at certain indices? Why don't you just use a `Map<XX, Person>` where `XX` is the class of `eligible`?

Comment: You can add more details to your question by using [edit] option placed below it.

Comment: here what is i, j. in sublist it is range

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the persons with `eligible="false"` as List. In java 8 you can use lambda expressions to filter list

```
List<Person> filteredresults = persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getEligibilty()==false).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by index pairs, but if you just want a list of eligible indexes, you can use a for loop to look to test the eligibility of each element. If eligible, add the index of that person to your other list. This will not modify your original list.

```
for(int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++) {
    if (personList.get(i).isEligible()) {
        otherList.add(i);
    }
}
```

If eligible is private, you will have to write an isEligible() method that simply returns the boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

There is not straight forward solution to your question, no inbuilt Java functionality. But this can help you.

```
    class Person {
        public boolean isEligible;
    }

    ArrayList<Person> persons;

    ArrayList<Pair<Integer,Integer>> retList = new ArrayList<>();
    int startIndex = -1;
    boolean currentSelection;

    for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
        if (startIndex < 0) {
            startIndex = i;
            currentSelection = persons.get(i).isEligible;

            continue;
        }

        if (currentSelection != persons.get(i).isEligible) {
            retList.add(new Pair<>(startIndex, i - 1));
            startIndex = i;
            currentSelection = persons.get(i).isEligible;

            continue;
        }
    }
    return retList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a flat `int[]` holding the change indices, rather than a list of pairs, since you're toggling between `true` and `false`. Here is a tested implementation using this paradigm, plus generating the sublists using [`List.subList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people =
            Arrays.asList(new Person(true), new Person(false),
                new Person(true), new Person(true), new Person(false),
                new Person(false), new Person(true));

        int[] changes = new int[people.size() + 1]; // allow for max changes
        Arrays.fill(changes, -1); // if an index is not used, will remain -1
        changes[0] = 0;
        int change = 1;
        boolean eligible = people.isEmpty() ? false : people.get(0).isEligible();
        for (int i = 1; i < people.size(); i++) {
            Person person = people.get(i);
            if (eligible != person.isEligible()) {
                changes[change++] = i;
                eligible = person.isEligible();
            }
        }
        changes[change] = people.size(); // end of last change segment

        List<List<Person>> sublists = new ArrayList<List<Person>>(change);
        for (int i = 0; i < change; i++) {
            sublists.add(people.subList(changes[i], changes[i + 1]));
        }
        System.out.println(sublists);
    }
}
```

Note that no copies are made of `people` or its elements; the sublists are merely views into the original list. The above code assumes a `Person` class defined something like this:

```
class Person
{
    boolean eligible;

    Person(boolean eligible) {
        this.eligible = eligible;
    }

    boolean isEligible() {
        return this.eligible;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person(" + isEligible() + ")";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LambdaJ](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures)  to easily extract a list of persons that is eligible.